# angular-translate-loader-partial not loading {parts} outside of .config() on initial load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate in my app and using angular-translate-loader-partial to load the resource modules as I need them.  If I try to use $translatePartialLoader.addPart(resource) on the initial load in a resource service, the "part" being loaded won't translate on the page although it shows it as being available using $translatePartialLoader.isPartAvailable(resource).

In the code below, the 'menus' resource gets translated fine.  The 'people' resource is "loaded" but the translation doesn't happen.

**Here is the chunk of code in angular.config -**

```
$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('menus');
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    urlTemplate: '/resources/files/{part}/{lang}.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');
```

**This call is being made by my resource service on the initial load -**

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart('people');
```

**I have the refresh being made in angular.run -**

```
run(function ($rootScope, $translate) {
    $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
        $translate.refresh();
    });
}).
```

Once the site is loaded, the call to $translatePartialLoader.addPart({part}); will work as designed.